# Yearling badge not awarded since assocation bonus

Tags: bug, badges, association-bonus, yearling-badge

Since I got the association bonus, November 6 2015, I didn't get the yearling badge. As I understand it, the association bonus doesn't count for the yearling badge. So I understand I didn't get the badge when I passed 800 points of reputation. But now I passed 900 points (910 as I wrote this question), and I didn't get it either. Has somebody an explanation for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have yearling 3 times on both [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=1351076) and [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=1351076).

Seeing as you've been a member for for 3 years and 7 months, everything seems to be correct.

Comment: That's not how I understand the badge: as soon as a user got 1 year on a stackexchange site, the badge is awarded every 200 points of reputation. I am wrong ?

Comment: Basically, you're wrong. The badge is awarded for each year you've been a member, as long as you have at least 200 rep.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Thank you for your explanations. That's seem more logical that the way I understood it :p

Comment: Does second Yearling badge don't give +100 reps?

Comment: @Sandeep: badges don't give rep. None of them do.

Comment: I was asking about association bonus. Do we get +100 reps after getting 2nd Yearling badge (i,e completed second year and got yearling badge) ?

Comment: The association bonus is not related to yearling. They're two different things.